# How does Fandango know my real credit card number through Apple Pay?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-pay

The Fandango app [recently released an update](http://www.imore.com/fandango-now-lets-you-snag-movie-tickets-apple-pay) featuring Apple Pay support. I just bought movie tickets using Apple Pay, but when I got my e-receipt, the "Payment Summary" section said:

> *Payment Summary*
>
> MasterCard ***********_ _ _ _ (Apple Pay):    [total cost]
>
> My Total Order [total cost]

The "[total cost]" and the four underscores are my edits for my own security, but the email displayed the actual last 4 digits of my credit card number. I've made purchases using my credit card on my Fandango account in the past, but if I used Apple Pay here, shouldn't Fandango be seeing only my device-specific number?

(iPhone 6, iOS 9.2 Public Beta 3)

Answer (score 1):

I found this on google:

[image]

It seams that they definitely should not have the last 4 digits of your card, but they do mention showing the last 4 digits of your device account number.